# How do I refresh a listbox display after I've run Close() on a window and then reopened it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I am trying to reopen a window which contains a user-manipulated listbox after closing. Everything works fine on the first instance, but when I try to open it after the first Close(), I just get a blank listbox and my initial list population doesn't occur.

I am calling the window in question like so:

```
    private void ContactButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContactPage = new ContactList();
        ContactPage.ShowDialog();
    }
```

I've tried Using to dispose of the old window, but that threw a type compatibility error. I tried moving my population code around from the initial call, to on Active, on Focus, on Load, etc. but with no success.

Comment: You clearly are using a new instance of the form..  Move the ContactPage declaration to class scope.  Check if it is null before calling new.  If it is, new it.  If it isn't, just show it.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, closing a form with `Close()`  doesn't dispose the class when using `ShowDialog()`, so you need to manually dispose.

[Docs for Form.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: That's what I want to happen. I pull my data from the main class and use it to populate the list. So each time the new listbox window opens, I want it to pull new data. For some reason, it's almost like it still exists even though I wanted it destroyed.

Comment: This is totally incorrect.  You can use this just EXACTLY as you intended to.  You just need to do what I mentioned above.  The variable for the dialog needs to be instanciated at a class level so the garbage collector knows not to delete it when the function exits.  With ShowDialog(), the resources WILL NOT be cleaned up by the GC.. The second paragraph in the docs Larry referenced clearly state that you need to call Dispose explicitly if you want it destroyed.  BTW, I have done this many many times/

Comment: My bad @Señor CMasMas, edited to reflect that. For some reason I read it as it was disposed when using ShowDialog instead of the reverse.